# Expected flatten_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was following the basic classification tutorial of [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification). Due to proxy reasons, I have to use the dataset offline. So, instead of using the fashion_mnist database, I am using mnist dataset.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, 

print_function, unicode_literals

# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense

# Noting class names
class_names = ['Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine']

# Load dataset
mnist = keras.datasets.mnist
path = 'C:/projects/VirtualEnvironment/MyScripts/load/mnist.npz'
(train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y) = mnist.load_data(path)

# Scale, so that training and testing set is preprocessed in the same way
train_x = train_x / 255.0
test_x = test_y / 255.0
train_y = tf.expand_dims(train_y, axis = -1)
test_y = tf.expand_dims(test_y, axis = -1)

#Build the model

#1. Setup the layers
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape = (28, 28)))
model.add(Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))


#2. Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=1)
print("Finished Training")

# Evaluate how the model performs on the test dataset
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_x,  test_y, verbose=2)
```

I am getting the following error: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (10000, 1).` I know very little about tensorflow, so if someone could guide me in the direction of a useful webpage, or could explain to me what the error means, I'd be much obliged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a typo in your code

change this

`test_x = test_y / 255.0`

to

`test_x = test_x / 255.0`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
(train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# Scale, so that training and testing set is preprocessed in the same way
train_x = train_x / 255.0
test_x = test_x / 255.0

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (28, 28)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))


#2. Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=1)

# Evaluate the model
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_x,  test_y, verbose=2)
```

The error you get means that you have incorrectly reshaped your input somewhere in your code.

Comment: I found the source of error which is `test_x = test_y / 255.0`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the array shape problem however i can help you out with the proxy so you can properly download the dataset. Assuming you have all clear from your IT for using the tools you are you can set pip proxy by exporting at the terminal level:

Let's say your login credential is COMPANY\username

```
export http_proxy=http://COMPANY%5Cusername:password@proxy_ip:proxy_port
export https_proxy=http://COMPANY%5Cusername:password@proxy_ip:proxy_port
```

If you're using a conda environment, .condarc at C:\Users\username and edit as:

```
channels:
- defaults

# Show channel URLs when displaying what is going to be downloaded and
# in 'conda list'. The default is False.
show_channel_urls: True
allow_other_channels: True

proxy_servers:
    http: http://COMPANY\username:password@proxy_ip:proxy_port
    https: https://COMPANY\username:password@proxy_ip:proxy_port


ssl_verify: False
```

Hope it helps. For debugging the array shape i suggest you print train_y and train_x shapes with train_y.shape() and train_x.shape() after expanding the dimensions. The error specifies that its getting a 10000D object with 1 value which shouldn't be the case.